# Strange Behavior packageToScan and annotatedClasses when using multiple sessionFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jndi, sessionfactory

So here it goes..

I have configured two jndi in my glassfish server for communicating two different databases.And in my applicationContext.xml I have following configuration

```
 <!-- Database connection 1 STARTS HERE-->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="JNDI1" jndi-name="jdbc/db1"/>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="JNDI1" />
<!--        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.test.db1.Person</value>  //THIS WORKS FINE
            </list>
        </property>-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.db1" /> //THIS IS STRANGE
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
   <!-- Database connection 1 ENDS HERE-->



    <!-- Database connection 2 STARTS HERE-->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="JNDI2" jndi-name="jdbc/db2" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory2"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="JNDI2" />
       <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.db2" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
 <!-- Database connection 2 ENDS HERE-->
```

In package `com.test.db1` I have only `Person` class and in `com.test.db2` package I have two entities named `Employee` and `Company`.

The problem occurs when I use ***packageToScan*** property in both SessionFactory beans all 3 tables are created in both databases.And when I explicitly define entity classes using ***annotatedClasses*** property tables are generated in relevant databases as configured in jndi.I am not getting why this kind of results I am getting while using ***packageToScan***.
I'll be grateful If someone can explain me in detail.

*Thank you*

Comment: I can't see why this is happening. Are you sure you are showing us exactly what's up?

Comment: yes, I am pretty sure and I was also wondering that is I have why asked here.

Comment: That is why I have asked here,Sorry for typo.